# Can variables passed to Pandoc be used in a lua-filter?

Tags: lua, pandoc

Does Pandoc expose variables set on the command line (`pandoc -V foo=bar`) to scripts running inside the [built in lua filter environment](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)? In other words if I run:

```
pandoc -V foo=bar --lua-filter=myfilter.lua
```

...what can I put in `myfilter.lua` to access `foo`?

Answer (score 5):

*(Since: pandoc 2.17)*

`PANDOC_WRITER_OPTIONS.variables["foo"]`

See https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-writeroptions

Answer (score 2):

This is documented a bit in the description for the `--metadata`:

> Like `--variable`, `--metadata` causes template variables to be set.
>   But unlike `--variable`, `--metadata` affects the metadata of the
>   underlying document (which is accessible from filters and may be
>   printed in some output formats) and metadata values will be escaped
>   when inserted into the template.

So, I think that using `-M` to set a variable will give you access to the variable inside your lua filter.